# Spring boot 2 activate spring profile using AWS API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a Spring boot 2 application using aws-serverless-java-container as per AWS guide https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/wiki/Quick-start---Spring-Boot2. 
I want to deploy my lambda in different stages and for which I want to invoke different spring profile so that I can invoke specific application-.properties file based on that. I know this could be done using Lambda environment variable by setting "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE" variable but I am wondering if I can use the API Gateway stage variable to set the profile value.